# Entity Framework 4 Partialy SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

Lets say i have this:

```
var entity = db.histories.GetWhere(x => x.Body == "MyBody").FirstOrDefault();
var entity2 = db.histories.GetWhere(x => x.Body == "MyBody2").FirstOrDefault();
        entity.From = "lmao!";
        entity2.From = "lmao2!";
```

now i know that to update i have to call `db.SaveChanges();`

my question is what if i want to update entity only and not entity2 ?

is that even possible ? could be simple im not sure.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You'd have to detach or clone entity2. And that just might cure the design problem that underlies this question.

Comment: Context is unit of work = use it as unit of work. Once you modify anything attached it will be saved. Don't modify attached items you don't want to save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either get the 2 entities from separate contexts:

```
var entity = db.histories.GetWhere(x => x.Body == "MyBody").FirstOrDefault();
var entity2 = differentDbInstance.histories.GetWhere(x => x.Body == "MyBody2").FirstOrDefault();
```

or retrieve from the same context but detach before making changes you dont want saved

```
db.Detach(entity2);
entity2.From = "lmao2!";
```

The latter is better design but you may need to former depending on the scenario

Comment: Just be aware that detaching an entity shreds its object graph (removes all attached child objects and collections) so referencing those child objects after the detach will result in a new read from the database.

Answer (score 3):

This has been asked before, and no, there is no way to accomplish this.

`entity` and `entity2` would have to be on different data contexts to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: @Henk Holterman, i dont understand if you mean that it is better that we cant do it , but if you mean that, can you explain why its better that its not possible ?

Comment: See my other comment. You shouldn't make changes to tracked entities if those changes shouldn't be saved.

Comment: I think what Henk is getting at is that allow partial saves would create lots and lots of hairy edge cases, and just in general allow for bad things to happen.  I wish I could come up with a concrete example off the top of my head