# EF4 - Extract identity within a transaction and perform subsequent SaveChanges(). Detach or multiple contexts?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

*(Note: I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415291/entity-framework-4-partialy-savechanges), but it's not exactly what I want to do.)*

I have a requirement where I need to do the following:

1. Create a new `Foo` entity
2. Upon creation of a Foo entity, create a new `FooAudit` entity and use the new identity value from the new `Foo` entity in the text description.  `FooAudit` has no reltionship with Foo, so the identity must be pulled manually from the creation of `Foo`.
3. Do these things in an all-or-nothing transaction, keeping the `EntityState` of the `Foo` record (`Added`) if I do not commit the transaction.

Do I use another context like so?

```
using (var fooContext = GetContext())
{

    fooContext.Foos.AddObject(new Foo());

    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
    {

        // Save Foo, while maintaining the Changed EntityState until AcceptAllChanges
        fooContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave);

        using (var auditContext = GetContext())
        {
            // Save FooAudit, maintaining the Changed EntityState until AcceptAllChanges
            auditContext.FooAudits.AddObject(new FooAudit());
            auditContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave);
            transaction.Complete();
            fooContext.AcceptAllChanges();
            auditContext.AcceptAllChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using another context as illustrated.